# Intune Graph API latency after GA

Tags: intune

Once Microsoft announced the Intune API GA early January 2018, the APIs are terribly slow. I observe it takes around 20 seconds for some APIs, whereas on an average it takes 7-9 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I work on Intune and would be happy to take a look at some of these for you. 
 Could you let us know:

1. Which APIs you are seeing performance issues with
2. A client request ID where you saw slow performance for each API in #1.  Also, this request must have been made within the last few weeks or we won't have the logs anymore.

Thanks

Comment: I just tried requesting the below API HTTP POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/iosManagedAppProtections/T_844405ca-bf3d-493c-b916-e2e3e1d2963a/targetApps

client-request-id = dfbe618b-6616-488a-b5b6-396bbb4af292

It took about ~9 seconds